# how to make this as bulkified

Tags: trigger

in my this code--

```
public class ClosingCaseOnClosingInvoice
{

  public static void CloseCase(List<Invoice__c> invoiceList)
  {
      List<CaseInvoice__c> caseList = [Select Case__c from CaseInvoice__c 
                                        where Invoice__c IN: invoiceList];  


  }
}
```

i know i can sort this out by using this-

```
List<CaseInvoice__c> caseList = [Select Case__c 
                                   from CaseInvoice__c 
                                  where Invoice__c =: invoiceList[0].id];
```

bt i want to write bulkified code which will be able to deal with multiple records at a time. Can someone please help me out.

Comment: Is the `closeCase` method being called inside a for loop? You need to add more details on how this method is being invoked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually in your class
You are quering `CaseInvoice__c` and assignning to `Case` object.

You need to assign to `CaseInvoice__c` instead `case`

```
 List<CaseInvoice__c> lstCaseInvoice= [Select Case__c 
                                         from CaseInvoice__c 
                                        where Invoice__c IN: invoiceList];
```

FYI: change your title looks like you are asking for code to bulkify.. it is bit confusing.

---

### Updates

### Short way

You can just query simply

```
 where Invoice__c IN: invoiceList
```

else another

### long way

first collect all the Invoice Ids in set and then perform query on Case Invoice

```
set<Id> setInvoiceIds = new set<Id>();
for(Invoice__c objInvoice: invoiceList){
setInvoiceIds.add(objInvoice.Id);
}
List<CaseInvoice__c> caseList = [Select Case__c 
                                   from CaseInvoice__c 
                                  where Invoice__c IN: setInvoiceIds];
```

Comment: ya actually i have corrected that but forgot to correct it here

Comment: now please can you help me out to make this code as bulkified code so that i can be able to deal multiple records

Comment: @RAT__ I can't see your complete code. I can see only 3 lines of code... how should I make 3 lines of  code bulkify?

Comment: actually i just want an idea how to pass multiple id of invoicelist.List<CaseInvoice__c> caseList = [Select Case__c                                    from CaseInvoice__c where Invoice__c =: invoiceList[0].id];   here i am only passing one invoiceList Id.

Comment: @RAT__ this is correct what you have tried in question i.e. `where Invoice__c IN: invoiceList` it will return all the records based on list of invoice ids.

Comment: @RAT__ check my updated ans.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/36952/discussion-between-rat-and-ratan).